# sshd log line format

Tags: ssh, logging

As maddening as it is, I can't find the SSH server log line format anywhere...

Specifically, my problem is that I know I'm being attacked, my log is full of lines like this:

```
Jun 26 08:55:51 singularity sshd[3233]: Connection closed by invalid user console 103.244.82.231 port 43554 [preauth]
```

but I can't find out what the `port` field means. I have a firewall that denies all, but a handful of ports, which means this can't be the local port, but then whose port does it refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *remote* port.

Every TCP socket is identified by a pair of addresses and a pair of ports. The remote port is used by servers (and by NAT gateways) to distinguish multiple connections by the same client. For logs to be useful, they need to show all information belonging to the 'remote' end, not just part of it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding! Though I'm still kinda curious as to whether there's any documentation on this - the manpages didn't specify anything, nor did Google reveal a _default_ format that might be customized.